# Android: Creating RecyclerView programmatically won't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in the xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTestMenuMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/rv" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and using it to show a dynamic list of buttons like this:

```
int buttonFontSize = 20;
RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);

LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
adapter = new RVAdapter_ButtonList(tests, null, this, buttonFontSize);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and all is working fine, but now all the buttons that are displayed vertically will be displayed horizontally and grouped into categories, so I need to create RecyclerViews dynamically, and I startd with a simple example of only one the next way with no success, as a blank screen is showing:

```
int buttonFontSize = 20;

RecyclerView rv = new RecyclerView(this);
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
rv.setLayoutParams(params);

LinearLayout llTestMenuMain = findViewById(R.id.llTestMenuMain);
llTestMenuMain.addView(rv);

LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
adapter = new RVAdapter_ButtonList(tests, null, this, buttonFontSize);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Any help on why I cannot make the dynamically created RecyclerView working will be much appreciated.

Edit 1:

I don't know if it is of any help, but noticed that creating the RV dynamically the adapter "onBindViewHolder" is never called (and the itemCount > 0, of course), does it when the RV is created in XML. Cannot find a solution to this... :(

Edit 2:

Also tried

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Just in case, to no avail too.

Comment: Try putting "rv.setLayoutManager(llm);" after you set the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @David Lee. I've tried your suggestion to no avail, still a blank screen is what I see.

Comment: What if you set the visibility of the `RecyclerView` (to *VISIBLE*) before you set the `LayoutManager`?

Comment: No @David Lee, no way. In fact creating the RecyclerView programmatically (and with testing purposes) I haven't set its visibility to Gone.

I don't know if it is of any help, but noticed that creating the RV dynamically the adapter "onBindViewHolder" is never called, does it when the RV is created in XML.

Cannot find a solution to this... :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found that putting the programmatically created RecyclerView inside a ScrollView makes it "magically" visible.

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace your code with this one:

```
int buttonFontSize = 20;

LinearLayout llTestMenuMain = findViewById(R.id.llTestMenuMain);

RecyclerView rv = new RecyclerView(this);
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
rv.setLayoutParams(params);
    
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
adapter = new RVAdapter_ButtonList(tests, null, this, buttonFontSize);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

llTestMenuMain.addView(rv);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MajedEddin. I've tried exactly what you suggested, setting the LayoutManager after setting the adapter, but I still see a blank screen. I'm not being able to create the RecyclerView dynamically. ¿Any other idea?